# How implement Filter Functionality for search

Tags: spring, filter, pattern-matching

Actually, i m implementing an addition search filter possiblity for categories etc.

An Example: 
I have an Article with Kategory, Origin, Producer, Supplier, Age, Qulity Marks etc.

Example Frontend Query: 
/search?cat="tablet"&cat="laptop"&age="2"&quality="second"

How can i generically query the searched values in the backend?
Is there any pattern or frameworks to handle it ?

( My Backend based on Spring Framework )

Answer (score -1):

query from where? Database? files? JDBC or JDBCTemplete (build-in Spring for Database query. Query from Files are complicated that you should deal with streams.

Comment: Query from Database. @Query is not generic